# Accessing ObservableCollection object using dynamic variable for integration testing (specflow)

Tags: c#, integration-testing, specflow

In my integration testing i'm using a dynamic variable like

```
dynamic variable = StateManager.DefaultState.DTE.GetObject("AutomationObject");
dynamic toolName = variable.GetVmObject("ToolName");
```

I have no problem here. Everything is working as expected. Using this dynamic variable "toolName" i could only access the public objects in my corresponding ViewwModel class. I was not able to access a `List<>` or `ObservableCollection<>` objects.

Is there any way to access these two objects using the dynamic variable "toolName"??

Comment: Check out the PrivateObject class

Comment: @bit: Sorry i didn't get your idea?

Comment: See this please, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/632100/Testing-private-methods-functions-using-VSTS-unit

Comment: And i'm not trying to access any private objects. Its a Public List<> or ObservableCollection<>. Each time i try to access i get exception like "dynamic object 'toolName' has no definition of 'list<>' "

Comment: this has nothing to do with specflow, or integration testing. What is the actual concrete type of `toolName`? please give us the definition of this concrete type and also show the code you are using which is generating the actual error. All you have done here is say that when you try and access the objects of type `List<>` but not show **how** you are trying to access those objects